# How to click every div with a specific class name

Tags: ruby, web-scraping, watir

I'm quite a newbie programmer so pardon me.
I have to open a bunch of popup windows from the main one, to scrape some data.
But there's not a link just many divs with the same class name, that when clicked open the popups.
How do I do that using watir?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can get all the divs with the matching class name using:

```
divs = browser.divs(class: 'whatever_your_class_is')
```

They can be clicked like any other element type - eg:

```
divs.each do |div|
  div.click
end
```

Comment: Thank you, I managed to make it works, but working on the popup window I found another similar problem that I'm not able to solve. I have extrapolated a div, saved into a variable, and now I have to click on it, but it gives me this error: `code undefined method 'click' for #<Watir::DivCollection:0x00005589f1acd890>`

Comment: Divcollection doesn't have the click method. Don't do `b.divs().click` it wouldn't work. Do `b.div().click`